# Get count of a 'x' item after a last 'y' item in a list

Tags: c#

Looking for an efficient way to get the count of item X (in our case "Yes") after a last item Y (in our case "No") from a list. Following is my solution:

```
List<string> MyList = new List<string> { "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"};
int LastNo = MyList.FindLastIndex(x => x.Equals("No"));

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (MyList.Count - LastNo); i++)
{
    if (MyList[LastNo + i].Equals("Yes"))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Is there an efficient way to do this that could handle large list?

Comment: Your question and example is confusing. What is the expected output?

Comment: Output just has to be a number. i.e. count of "Yes" after a last "No"

Comment: But what is the expected output for your particular example?

Comment: Output in my example will be 2

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Why 2? Elaborate

Comment: Because there are two "Yes" at index 10 and 11 at after the last "No" at 9

Answer (score 0):

Initialise a `count` variable.
You should start counting from last to first in a `for` loop.

For loop should be lost this.

```
for (int i = yourList.Length - 1; i >= 0; i—)
```

Keep on incrementing the count value.

And break the loop as soon as you get first No.

Print the `count` variable.

And please don’t name your `List` variable as `Array`. It will confuse the reader.